# mysql join with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, conditional-statements

I have two table with this structure

```
categories
--------------------------------
id  | create
1   | 2012-12-01 12:00:00
2   | 2012-12-01 12:00:00

category_i18ns
--------------------------------
category_id     | lang  | title
1               | en    | home page
1               | de    | HomE PAGEa
1               | fa    | خانه
2               | en    | about
```

some categories have all languages data and some another havnt. for example category id 2 just have `en` translated title. i want to have a query that first check the current language for retrieve title and then if not exist then show another ones.

i have a query to get current category data with i18n data
in this current example `de` is default language. for category id `1` we have `de` title but for category `2` we dont. so i want english version as title of category

```
SELECT * FROM `mhf_swe_ndzhmju3_test`.`categories` AS `Category`
LEFT JOIN `mhf_swe_ndzhmju3_test`.`category_i18ns` AS `CategoryLocale` ON (
`CategoryLocale`.`category_id` = `Category`.`id`
AND `CategoryLocale`.`lang` = 'de')
```

desire out put for 'de' language

```
Category.id     CategoryLocale.title    CategoryLocale.lang
1               HomE PAGEa              de
2               about                   en
```

Comment: If you have `en` and `fa` for category 2 but haven't `de` which language you must choose?

Comment: Can you please mention properly the output you expect ?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan not important. first that mysql serverd

Comment: desire output added. please check and suggest the query. ty

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
SELECT Category.id,
        COALESCE(a.lang, b.lang) lang,
        COALESCE(a.title, b.title) title
FROM   categories AS Category
      LEFT JOIN category_i18ns AS a
           ON a.category_id = Category.id AND a.lang = 'de'
      LEFT JOIN category_i18ns AS b
           ON b.category_id = Category.id AND b.lang = 'en'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec947/17)

Comment: if we dont know which language added to the special category ? how can i retrive them. for example category id 3 added just via `fr` language and dont have any another language

Comment: Aren't you making an assumption here that you will have an entry for `en` in all the categories ?

Comment: @sub_stantial nope .. there is no major default language for all category.

Comment: @sweb : Yes i agree. Anyway my question was for Kuya John.

Comment: so what's the query guys :D

Comment: @sweb your question was notclear that's why i assume every category has english. let's try to work it out. follow-up question, do category has atleast one language?

Comment: Please please always explain your answers on Stack Overflow.   This is unhelpful to the OP, researchers, and all future askers who have their question closed by this page.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an order of preference,
left join all languages and put them to coalesce in order of preference:

```
SELECT Category.id,
    COALESCE(a.lang, b.lang, c.lang, d.lang) lang,
    COALESCE(a.title, b.title, c.title, d.title) title
FROM   categories AS Category
  LEFT JOIN category_i18ns AS a
       ON a.category_id = Category.id AND a.lang = 'de'
  LEFT JOIN category_i18ns AS b
       ON b.category_id = Category.id AND b.lang = 'en'
  LEFT JOIN category_i18ns AS c
       ON c.category_id = Category.id AND c.lang = 'fr'
  LEFT JOIN category_i18ns AS d
       ON d.category_id = Category.id AND d.lang = 'es';
```

If you want to get a text from a random language, use this query:

```
SELECT Category.id,
        COALESCE(a.lang, b.lang) lang,
        COALESCE(a.title, b.title) title
FROM   categories AS Category
      LEFT JOIN category_i18ns AS a
           ON a.category_id = Category.id AND a.lang = 'de'
      LEFT JOIN category_i18ns AS b
           ON b.category_id = Category.id
GROUP BY Category.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2beaf/5

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is not the best solution, but I think should work fine :

```
SELECT * FROM categories c INNER JOIN category_i18ns t1 
ON c.id = t1.category_id AND t1.lang = 'de'

UNION 

SELECT * FROM categories c LEFT JOIN category_i18ns t2 
ON c.id = t2.category_id and t2.lang != 'de' 
WHERE t2.category_id not in
   (SELECT DISTINCT category_id FROM category_i18ns WHERE lang = 'de') 
GROUP BY c.id
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcfe6/6)